# If we use multiple users GPS tracking code for mobile phones, is there any distance limit between two or more phones?

Tags: firebase, mobile, gps

I have developed a mobile app (hybrid app), which is to track **multi user in real time using firebase**.

My question is:

1. Is there's any **restrictions** on the **maximum distance between the users** (mobile devices) or it is **unlimited**? (since the app connecting with firebase cloud)

Comment: show how you are using firebase and where you are getting the gps data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase services don't care where in the world clients are accessing it, nor does it care about the distances between the clients.  It's just moving data around, wherever it comes from.